# Can not uninstall VS2013 CE

Tags: visual-studio-2013, uninstallation

I had VS2013 Community Edition installed on another hard disk. Unfortunately this hard disk died a sudden death some days ago.

Now I cannot uninstall / reinstall VS2013 Community Edition, because it always cancels the process saying that he is missing several packages.

Also the command `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force` fails with the same report.

Is there any way I can "manually" remove some files or registry entries so that the setup thinks there is no VS2013 installed?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem.

Partially followed this guide: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248697

Used `Process Monitor`, launching the `vs_community.exe` filtering for `VS`, `Visual Studio`, `12.0`, etc.

Also `Total Commander`, searching for files and directories containing mentioned strings and deleting them.

Additionally removed tons of Registry Entries using `regedit` and searching for those strings.

Hope I didn't break anything important in the process. :D

Then launching `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force` one last time. This time it went through without aborting.

And finally I got this much desired screen ... Phew!

[image]